# UImage? isn't convertible to UIImage: Xcode throws error when trying to use original image

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller

```
 func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    // The info dictionary may contain multiple representations of the image. You want to use the original.
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as?
        UIImage else {
        fatalError("Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I am trying to build an iOS app that allows you to pick an image from the library, but it keeps failing with the error "UIImage? is not convertible to UIImage. Is there a way to fix this error or bypass it as of now? I am running Xcode 10.1 on MacOS 10.14.

Comment: Start by using the correct method signature: `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])`.

Comment: On your guard statement I think you don’t need the ? After the as.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `.originalImage` with `UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage`

This worked for me.

**Xcode version**: 10.1

**Swift version**: 4.0

Answer (score -1):

info[.originalImage] is a Any? value. Si it is like it can contain a UIImage? value or nil. So, try:

```
guard guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage?  else { ... }
```

adding that question mark to UIImage. That's all.

Comment: As @rmaddy has already commented above the signature of the delegate method is wrong. The info parameter must be of type '[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]', see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontrollerdelegate/1619126-imagepickercontroller