# Crash _assertionFailure with imagePickerController

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I've following crash log from crashlytics and code below.

I'm aware that fatalError will crash app. What I wanted to ask is that if there is anything wrong with the code snippet which may be causing error and if we can avoid it?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libswiftCore.dylib             0x1b013b5c4 _assertionFailure(_:_:file:line:flags:) + 800
1  MyApp                0x1045d7d34 specialized ChatController.imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) + 1632 (ChatController.swift:1632)
2  MyApp                0x1045d2c1c @objc ChatController.imagePickerController(_:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:) + 4343098396 (<compiler-generated>:4343098396)
3  UIKitCore                      0x1a63368bc -[UIImagePickerController _imagePickerDidCompleteWithInfo:] + 120
4  UIKitCore                      0x1a63361b8 __60-[UIImagePickerController didSelectMediaWithInfoDictionary:]_block_invoke + 48
5  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a25a2ec4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
6  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a25a433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1a25b0600 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 832
8  CoreFoundation                 0x1a287f41c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 16
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1a287a034 __CFRunLoopRun + 1708
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1a2879660 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 480
11 GraphicsServices               0x1acc8a604 GSEventRunModal + 164
12 UIKitCore                      0x1a6a4e15c UIApplicationMain + 1944
13 MyApp                0x1043f37a0 main + 21 (ProfileViewController.swift:21)
14 libdyld.dylib                  0x1a26f51ec start + 4
```

ChatController.swift:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any])
{
    
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        // Following line is 1632
        fatalError("Error: Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
    }
    // other code...
}
```

Comment: Well, your code _says_ to crash. You can hardly complain if you _do_ crash. You should write code that fails gracefully.

Comment: Your code bears an astonishing resemblance to the question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137795/uimage-isnt-convertible-to-uiimage-xcode-throws-error-when-trying-to-use-orig/53138742#53138742

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I wanted to ask if there is something wrong with the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obvious you're getting the crash because you're asking the compiler to do so with `fatalError`. If you're trying to avoid the crash then remove the `fatalError` and maybe handle the event where `originalImage` is unavailable.

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    guard let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage else {
        print("Error: Expected a dictionary containing an image, but was provided the following: \(info)")
        // maybe set a placeholder image to the UIImageView
        return
    }
    // other code...
}
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. I'm aware that fatalError will crash. What I wanted to ask was that if there is anything wrong with the code which is causing error or it's just natural and may happen once a while?